# How To Add Drop Shadow in Wix Editor X

Tags: css, velo, dropshadow

I've recently built a website in Wix's new Editor X.

Does anyone know how to add a drop shadow in Editor X?
In the old wix is was a standard text effect, I can't find anyway to access CSS.

It looks like it will allow javascript functions but that seems like the long way 'round.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting the .html property of your object (#id). For example:

```
$w("#id").html = "<p style='filter: drop-shadow(1px 8px 4px #4444dd)'>test</p>"
```

Below snippet shows the result in pure HTML.

```html
<p style='filter: drop-shadow(1px 8px 4px #4444dd)'>test</p>
```